The "Clamp To" Constraint and the speed of movement

As you can see I have three objects in this scene, and the Cube is Parent to the Circle and the Empty. You can also see that the Empty has a Constraint, namely "Clamp To". Because of this I can grab the Cube and type GY (or GYY for that matter) and then move the mouse. The Empty will circle around the Circle (which is actually turned into a half-circle).
Why this? Because the Empty can control armature and a leg's walk cycle.
So what's the problem then? I would like the Empty to move faster when it is in the upper half-circle shape of the Circle path, than when it is in the straight lower part. Since the half-circle shape is 57% longer than the straight lower part, I would like the Empty to move 57% faster when it is up than when it is down. That would mean that the Empty would spend the same time in the half-circle as in the straight part.

Interesting. I see that changing radius of control points has effect, but not localized for parts of the curve.
